# Batch IF variable comparison mysteriously not working

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I would like to create a batchfile which reads 2 different values and based on how they compare it proceeds accordingly. However, the comparison never works. The code is:

```
REM string1 and string2 contain the following test string "---------- COUNT.TXT 14" from which the number at the very right will be extracted in the next lines:
REM read numbers from strings and save as variables

set /a var1 =%:string1:~22,2%
set /a var2 =%:string2:~22,2%

IF #var1# == #var2# (
...
)
```

Any ideas on why the condition/comparison never works? "SET var" reveals both variables being equal (var1=14, var2=14), but nonetheless in the IF they are not recognized as such. Any guidance will be much appreciated!

The strings btw. are the second output line of a find /c (find and count).

Comment: 1/ There is a space at the end of your variable's names. 2/ Don't use `/a`. Just `set var=blah`.

Comment: thanks for the tips, but there are no changes yet with:                                 set var1=%:string1:~22,2%
set var2=%:string2:~22,2%
IF #var1# == #var2# (...)

Comment: There are spaces in your if statement.

Comment: @Noodles - those issues are frequently problems, but not in this case. The extracted value is a number, so SET /A is fine, and SET /A works OK with extra spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `IF %var1% == %var2%` ... (not `#`) or to be sure: `IF "%var1%" == "%var2%"` ...

By the way: your string looks nearly like output from `find /c` If that's true, and the missing colon is just a typo, you can split your string with:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%i in ("%string1%") do set /a var1=%%i
```

or even simpler:

```
set /a var1=%string1:*: =%
```

(remove from the beginning until (including) `:` (colon-space) (this wouldn't even need the `/a`)

No need to care, if it's two digits or one or six...

Comment: The IF works perfectly now. And the output is indeed the second line read from a written output of `find /c` (and there was a missing colon in my description).  The string usage you propose is way better as well not being limited to the number of digits possible. Thanks a lot!

Comment: One remark here is that eventhough the string extraction works perfectly with both:  `set /a var1=%string1:*: =%` and `set var1=%string1:*: =%` it seems that only if we used the `/a` switch we will be able to get the IF working, e.g.: `IF NOT "%var1%" == "%var2%" (...)`. I hope to be correct (even if extremely naive at it).

Answer (score 1):

You have extra, unwanted colons in your assignment. The two lines should read as follows:

```
set /a var1 =%string1:~22,2%
set /a var2 =%string2:~22,2%
```

The space after the variable name is OK, but only when using SET /A. It would be good to get out of the habit of putting a space there so that the assignment works properly without the `/a` option.

The following creates variables with a space in the name - normally not a good idea:

```
set var1 =%string1:~22,2%
set var2 =%string2:~22,2%
```

So it is better to use

```
set /a var1=%string1:~22,2%
set /a var2=%string2:~22,2%
```

or

```
set var1=%string1:~22,2%
set var2=%string2:~22,2%
```

Comment: Excellent suggestion, now I realize the relevance of that seemingly harmless space when it comes to setting values to variables in cmd. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`REM string1 and string2 contain e.g. the following test string "---------- COUNT.TXT: 14"
set /a var1=%string1:*: =%
set /a var2=%string2:*: =% 
IF NOT "%var1%"=="%var2%" (echo not equal)`

Summarizing suggestions this is how the working code looks like, special care should be taken to match the syntax including seemingly harmless spaces.